# Why are thousands of random folders being opened on a shared network drive by a Mac running MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6) on new Windows 2016 network

Tags: windows, networking, mac, windows-server-2016

We recently installed Windows 2016 on a Dell Server and noticed that two of the Macs (running MacOS High Sierra (10.13.6)) on the network are opening thousands of folders on our shared network drives. The one other Mac on the network (running 10.11.6) is not  opening folders. Are there configurations on the network or individual computers to stop this or prevent this from happening?

Comment: When we close the folders from the network management screen within a few minutes they begin to open up again.

Comment: Can you provide any screenshots?

Comment: Is the computer trying to index network drives for searching?

Comment: We have spotlight running on the macs...we are going to check to see if it is indexing our shared network drives. But even if it is doesn't seem it should be perpetually indexing drives for days.

Comment: My boss a few years ago (Dev Manager) installed some indexing product from Google on his desktop at work to try it out. Some time later he was approached by a very annoyed group of Network Admins and told to desist immediately.

Comment: ok ha. we have tried adding the network drive causing the issue to the privacy panel of spotlight but when we restart the computer that is the only network drive missing from the privacy panel. That is the drive where all the folders are open on the network.

Comment: Try running `sudo fs_usage | grep "/Volumes/sharename"` on a misbehaving Mac client, and see if it shows what process is opening files on the server.

Comment: my coworker tried running the command on the shared drive causing issues and he got a 'resource busy' message